# Event Repots in 3 dimensions (piwik)

Tags: javascript, web-analytics, matomo, event-tracking

I'm using piwik, but I have a question about the Events Report. I would like to have for each Categories, the corresponding Actions, and for each Actions the corresponding Names. Like this : Categories -> Actions -> Name

Because right now I can see only 2 dimensions for the Events. So is it possible to have 3 dimensions ? or do I have to create my own report to get this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own report to get this (it's recommended to pre-archive it). Basically you will have to group the data by the 3 mentioned dimensions.